# How do I handle recursive repr()'s in Python?

Tags: python

I've written a container type in Python and I'm trying to write a robust `__repr__` method that correctly handles the case where the container contains itself.

For example, here's what the built-in `list` does:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x.append(x)
>>> repr(x)
'[[...]]'
```

Container types written in C for CPython can achieve this functionality by using `Py_ReprEnter` and `Py_ReprLeave`.  Is there equivalent functionality in pure-Python, or do I need to create my own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own, but it's a bit of a pain if you want to do it properly: you shouldn't store a ‘being repr'd’ marker flag on the object itself because that's not thread-safe. Instead you can store a thread-local set of your instances that are being repr'd.

A much cheaper solution is to depend on a built-in `repr` that takes care of recursion, eg.:

```
def __init__(self, *list):
    self._list= list
def __repr__(self):
    return 'mything('+repr(self._list)[1:-1]+')')
```

As long as *one* object in a recursion loop causes `Py_ReprEnter` to happen, `repr` can't form a complete loop.

> How do I create a thread-local set of instances?

With the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module:

```
class MyThing(object):
    _local= threading.local()
    _local.reprs= set()

    def __repr__(self):
        reprs= MyThing._local.reprs
        sid= id(self)
        if sid in reprs:
            return 'MyThing(...)'
        try:
            reprs.add(sid)
            return 'MyThing(%r)' % self.something
        finally:
            reprs.remove(sid)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to compute the repr string dynamically, so I can't depend on the built-in repr() in the way that you describe.  How do I create a thread-local set of instances?

Comment: @DanielStutzbach , why wrapped in try/finally block?

Comment: @akaRem: `self.something` is a placeholder for some more complex work involving recursion. On a bad day something in there might cause an exception. If that happens we want to make sure the `reprs` list is cleared out on the way back out otherwise it will accumulate instances as the errors pile up, causing more and more `MyThing`s to render as `MyThing(...)` even when there is no recursion.

Comment: Your `self._list` is actually a tuple, which adds an undesirable comma if it only has a single element ... also note that the `[1:-1]` just cuts off the `'('` and `')'` which you then immediately add again - thus it's equivalent to just `return 'mything%r' % self._list`

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Python 3 you can make use of the [reprlib.recursive_repr](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr) decorator.