# Infinite loop problem in python class set output

Tags: python

I created this Level class with two objects: name & the precondition of level.
With the property function at the end, I want to get a set of all preconditions for a certain level.
(For example: for Level 3 the precondition is `{Level 2}`, and for Level 2 the precondition is `{Level 1}`, so the all preconditions of Level 3 is `{Level 1, Level 2}`)

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self,
        name: str,
        preconditions: list[Level] = [],
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.preconditions = set(preconditions)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Level(name="{self.name}", preconditions={self.preconditions})'

    @property
    def all_preconditions(self) -> set[Level]:
        preconditions = set()
        for p in self.preconditions:
            preconditions.update(p.preconditions)
            p = p.preconditions
        return preconditions
```

My code works so far, but I have a loop problem. There are some Levels who are dependent on each other. For example: Level A precondition = {Level B} & Level B precondition = {Level A}.

In this case, I'm getting an infinite loop of preconditions as an output. For example:

```
{Level(name="A", preconditions={Level(name="B", preconditions={Level(name="A", precondition={Level(name="B", preconditions=set(...)}
```

Could anyone help me how I stop the loop and only get one precondition?

Comment: FWIW, be very careful with [`preconditions: list[Level] = []`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Also, `p = p.preconditions` doesn't really do anything...

Comment: What output do you expect? You do have an infinite loop of preconditions. I'm not sure how otherwise you expect Python to express that

Comment: @DeepSpace
I would expect to have Level A precondition = {Level B} & Level B precondition = {Level A}. 
I still need the for loop to reach the precondition of a precondition (for example example 1 above in my text).

Comment: But `self.preconditions` is part of the object's `repr`, the infinite loop is just in the object's representation string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle recursive repr()'s in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858921/how-do-i-handle-recursive-reprs-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

### NOTE: old answer re-done completely

I misunderstood part of the question, I thought that the problem was with the `all_preconditions` method, not the `__repr__` part.

A simple solution would be to not format using `__repr__` when pritning preconditins, so `return f'Level(name="{self.name}", preconditions={[p.name for p in self.preconditions]})'`.

The better solution would be to make `__repr__()` not recurse, and it turns out, there's already a solution for that - explicitly call `repr()`:
`return f'Level(name="{self.name}", preconditions={repr(self.preconditions)})'`

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858921/how-do-i-handle-recursive-reprs-in-python) by googling "python repr recursive data type".

### EDIT 2:

If you make the `Level` class into a `dataclass` using the [dataclasses module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), the auto-generated `__repr__` is already recursion-free.

### EDIT 3:

I did some more digging, and it turns out, that the `repr()` recursion-breaking is only happening for builtin types, for example `list`, `tuple`, `dict` or `set`, and **can not be easily implemented for your own types**, which is a shame. The fact that you use lists/dicts saves you now, as they will stop the recursion.

Luckily, dataclasses seem to also define the default `repr` with this feature.